# How do I do date manipulation in SpEL?

Tags: java, spring, spring-el, date-manipulation

How can I do date manipulation in the Spring Expression language?

```
<si:service-activator id="entryReader" expression="@blogEntryReader.getEntriesBetweenDates(payload.startDate, payload.startDate **PLUS 30 DAYS**)" input-channel="blogEntryReaderChannel"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the java.util.Calendar doesn't have a builder API so it's not SpEL-friendly. One solution would be to use a helper class...

```
public static class CalendarManip {

    public static Date addDays(Date date, int days) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 30);
        return cal.getTime();
    }
}
```

Then, in SpEL...

```
T(foo.CalendarManip).addDays(payload.startDate, 30)
```

You could also use a <int-groovy:script/> if you don't want a helper class.

Answer (score 1):

```
T(org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils).addDays(payload.startDate, 30)
```

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: A nice simple solution here... I would've thought it's fairly straightforward what's happening here...? Calling the static method addDays on the DateUtils class of apache commons

Comment: Neat solution, but unfortunately in newer version of Thymeleaf I get "Instantiation of new objects and access to static classes or parameters is forbidden in this context"

Answer (score 0):

If you have the access a tidier way to do this would be by writing the date manipulation functions you need and injecting them into the SpelEvaluationContext:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-ref-functions