# Select entity using between two offset times

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In my entity I have two values `openTime` and `closeTime` both of the type `OffsetTime`, now I want to retrieve the entity where the current time is between the openTime and closeTime, but the problem I now have what if `openTime = '23:00:00'` and `closeTime = '05:00:00'`, meaning that the entity is open at evening and during night.
I have the following query:

```sql
SELECT s FROM ShopArticle s LEFT JOIN FETCH s.openTimes t WHERE t.openTime < :time AND t.day = :day`
```

where `:time` is of type `OffsetTime` and `:day` of type `DayOfWeek`. I can't change openTime to DateTime or sth else, so how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Without the over-night problem the important part of the where clause should look like this

```sql
WHERE t.openTime <= :time 
AND :time <= t.closeTime
```

With the over-night issue you'd need something like

```sql
WHERE (
   t.openTime <= :time 
   AND :time <= t.closeTime
   AND t.day = :day
)
OR (
    (
        (t.openTime <= :time AND t.day = :day) 
    OR 
        (:time <= t.closeTime AND t.day = :day -1)
    )
    AND t.openTime > t.closeTime
)
```

You can't do date calculations in JPQL though, so `:day -1` won't work.

Since you seem to use Spring Data JPA, you can solve [that problem with a SpEL expression](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions). How to do that exactly depends on how you pass `:day` to the query. If it is actually a date-like value, this question and it's answers might be helpful: [How do I do date manipulation in SpEL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9832090/66686)

Unfortunately JPQL doesn't really have ways to do date calculations, which would come in handy, because you'd have to do something like this: